Debugging 24V H-bridge Design with gate drivers and discrete MOSFETS
This is one of my first electronics projects. I was basing my design on this schematic that I found. I have run into a bunch of issues and would appreciate any assistance.
So this is the schematic that I found on a website (https://www.pcbway.com/blog/technology/Powerful_H_Bridge_DC_Motor_Driver.htm):

I replicated the entire design on a breadboard. My motor specifications are:
Voltage: 24 V (nominal)
No load current: 0.60 A
Nominal Current: 6A
Stall Current: 80 A
This is the breadboard prototype that I made.

Initially, I made a major mistake where I forgot to make the connection between VS (pin 6) of the gate driver and the drain of the low-side MOSFET. But when I fixed the connection, my motor driver still would not work properly.
This is what happens:
I connected the VCC to 24 V and ran a 50% duty cycle for the PWM signal from an Arduino expecting 12V output from my power supply (50% to the left gate driver and 0% to the right).
Instead, it started at a low 1 V and slowly crept up all the way to 24 V (the supply output on the display).
Initially, the motor vibrates struggling to spin, and then just doesn't budge. And then the circuit stops reacting to anything.
Questions that I am very confused about because I only have one set of materials left to remake this and don't want to blow it:

Is the design feasible for a motor driver, even if it's not perfect, will it work most of the time or are there any major flaws that I do not understand because of my lack of expertise?

Was the loss of functionality due to my incorrect connection initially and what components might I have damaged and need replacing (I know difficult to tell from a post but I am desperate)??

Are the bulk decoupling capacitors to overkill for the motor I have?

Is there any obvious flaw in the breadboard prototype that I posted? (I tried to keep the wiring as neat as possible)??


Thanks so much in advance for any help you all can offer and let me know if any other piece of information would help pinpoint the source of the issue.

Without heatsink, it should be difficult ...

Without thermal considerations, is there any other major flaw in the design? I could buy MOSFET heatsinks.

PWM2 is "complementary" to PWM1. 50 % should be the "rest" state ... if you need direct and reverse working. Try with a motor with "lower" current and power supply limited with current.

”major mistake where I forgot to make the connection between VS (pin 6) of the gate driver and the drain of the low-side MOSFET” That’s effectively a shorted output. Your 2104 may have suffered permanent damage from it.

@Antonio51 I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. I have 50% duty for the left half bridge and 0% for the right. Aiming for clockwise rotation at 12 V. Is that not the correct approach?

@winny I really hope that is the case. I never noticed the MOSFETs or any other component get extremely hot or anything, and since the limit of the 2104 is 12V, I'm guessing the 24 V damaged it. I'm not entirely sure though why that "effectively a shorted output" as you mentioned.

If you need only a clockwise rotation, then you need only 1/2 circuit (left part).

@Antonio51 I want direction control as well though. I just described how I was testing the circuit. i was testing it for 50% PWM duty cycle CW rotation.

The left side of R2 (low side gate resistor) is not connected.

Gate drivers like this switch relatively large currents in a handfull of nanoseconds. dI/dt is off the charts. The tiniest stray inductance will create large ringing that destroys components. You can't build this on a prototype board. Design a proper PCB.
